# Positive average but negative z-value (Wilcoxon Signed rank test)

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank

Can anyone explain why I get a negative z-value when I perform a Wilcoxon test but my average is positive?

Comment: Please supply the details: describe the data and show what calculations you performed, along with the specific results.

Answer (score 4):

Examples are easy to construct.

Here's one such data set:

```
-0.38 -0.32 -0.29 -0.27 -0.25 -0.23 -0.21 -0.19 
-0.17 -0.15 -0.13 -0.11 -0.08 -0.02  3.00
```

Almost all the data are negative, but the mean is positive. In the plot below the data values are represented by black bars:

[image]

Note there's a large outlier at 3.

The blue vertical line marks the location estimate corresponding to the signed rank test (with a 95% CI which clearly excludes 0), and the red line marks the mean. The mean is strongly affected by that outlier; the pseudomedian is not. This is one way to get the effect you describe.

There's no particular reason to think that two different ways of summarizing the data will give the same information.

Answer (score 2):

The z-value is related to the signed ranks, not to the original values. So it is possible.